# Can't capture audio with cordova / phone gap on nexus 7

Tags: android, cordova, nexus-7

I am using teleriks icenium to develop a mobile app.  It uses phone gap / Cordova and I have just loaded the example capture program as per http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html.

It works fine capturing video and pictures but not audio clips.  When running the code,and error code 3 is received.

I can't see any where on the nexus 7 to set a default audio capture device but have a feeling the api is just not being able to launch the appropriate programme for audio.

Any ideas?